# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`. The code looks fine to me, what am i missing?

```
function SaveGridster(jsonState) {
        console.log('SaveGridster'); // I CAN SEE THIS IN CONSOLE
        var msttou = {
            "srno": "1",
            "module": "ABT Meter Details",
            "userid": "SYS",
            "jsondata": "jsonState"
        };


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            url: BaseAddress + "InstanceDataAPI",
            dataType: "json",
            data: JSON.stringify(msttou),
            success: function (response) {
                console.log('success');
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

**CONSOLE:**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at jQuery.extend.parseJSON (http://localhost:2402/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js:564:23)
    at ajaxConvert (http://localhost:2402/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js:8443:19)
    at done (http://localhost:2402/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js:8199:15)
    at XMLHttpRequest.callback (http://localhost:2402/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js:8792:8)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It would appear the error lies within the AJAX response your function is getting. The SyntaxError is issued by the JSON parser. Convert the dataType to 'text' to disable JSON parsing.

Comment: Isn't this a comment?

Comment: It is, probably, but I can't comment yet :(

Comment: The SaveGridster function is getting executed that is for sure. Because I can see the first console log message in the console. If there is some problem prior to this code I dont think this function would have executed right?

Comment: You are right. It would seem the error message you see is caused by the parsing of the AJAX response. Can you check that in developer tools?

Comment: Can you try to make the same request with dataType: 'text'?

Comment: Great :) I've updated my answer to reflect that, so you can accept it :)

Comment: I will, but what if I want to pass it as JSON?

Comment: Then the response should be valid JSON.

Comment: Is it not valid Json? The one i posted?

Comment: You posted your function which makes an AJAX call, not the response from that AJAX call. You can see the response by using `console.log(response)` in your success function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109128/discussion-between-arbaaz-and-daan-meijer).

Comment: But then how will i get response when i am not able to successfully execute the call? It doesnt go inside success function